# Ошибка при компиляции в g++

Tags: c++, g++

```
$ g++ Scan.cpp -o Scan

Scan.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Scan.cpp:13:9: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} to ‘const char*’
   13 |  system(ScanCom);
      |         ^~~~~~~
      |         |
      |         std::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}
```

Код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string file;
    string fileS = file + ".jpg";
    string ScanCom = "scanimage -p > /home/themihai/scans/" + fileS;
    cout << "FileName:";
    cin >> file;
    system(ScanCom);
}
```

Comment: `system(ScanCom.c_str());`

Comment: `cin >> file;` должно быть ДО того, как собирается строка fileS

Comment: А при чём тут g++? Оно что, где-то ещё компилируется?

Answer (score 2):

Пойдём по порядку:

1. Это не ошибка, но `stdlib.h` - это файл из С. В С++ используйте `cstdlib`.
2. На момент выполнения строки `string fileS = file + ".jpg";`, переменная `file` содержит в себе пустую строку. Читайте строку до того, как будете её использовать.
3. Функция `system` ожидает `char*` или `const char*`, а не обьект `string`. Метод `c_str()` может Вам помочь. Вызвайте так: `system(ScanCom.c_str());`.